# server version mismatch postgresql pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pg-dump, postgresql-9.3, ubuntu-13.04

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to export my database...

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.3.1; pg_dump version: 9.1.11
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

The problem is I cannot update from 9.1.11 to 9.3.1 because of my ubuntu version on my client machine. I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 raring ringtail and as you can see in [this distributions link](http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/) the ultimate postgresql version for ubuntu is 12.04 precise pangolin.

Any possible solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll either have to (1) dump remotely on the server, or (2) install postgresql 9.3 from source (it's not tricky once you have the relevant development packages installed), or (3) upgrade your ubuntu to "trusty"

Comment: You're right. In fact I was applied your first solution before but I was dealing with the problem of importing the data later in the client. I guess I can apply one of the two next solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @RichardHuxton: Please convert your comment to an asnwer, so we can vote on it.

Answer (score -1):

As previously commented the solution is to use a `pg_dump` compatible with the server version. The alternatives are:

1. Run `pg_dump` from the server. This means you have to have a local or remote connection to server (via ssh for example)
2. Install later version of `pg_dump`. Note that even pgAdmin includes `pg_dump` so you don't necessarily have to install PostgreSQL package on the client.